# How to prevent sql injection in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sql-injection

I am using below jpa code. How can we prevent below code from sql injections?

```
List<Document> docs= em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Document c WHERE c.docId = :docId ", Document.class)
                .setParameter("docId", docId).getResultList();
```

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/preventing_injection_in_jpa_query

Comment: It already is protected against SQL injection. Your code is using parameters. Why do you think it isn't protected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058760/prevent-jpql-query-sql-injection

Answer (score 1):

It already is protected against SQL injection. Your code is using parameters.
Also if you want, you can use Criteria APIs to build the same query.