# Do Spring Boot and JpaRepository prevent sql injection and xss atack?

Tags: sql, spring, xss, sql-injection

I want to prevent "sql injection" and "xss atack" in my spring boot project.My example below of question.

1. Do JpaRepository method like findOne() prevent sql injection?
2. Should i use like StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4() method for "PersonelNumber" parameter xss atacks?
   (ex : `..searchUser/<script>alert('1')</script>` )

EmployeeController

```
@GetMapping("/searchUser")
    public ResponseEntity searchUserByNo(@RequestHeader("personelNumber")String PersonelNumber) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok(new BaseResultsDTO<>(employeeService.getEmployeeByNo(PersonelNumber)));
}
```

EmployeeService

```
public Employee getEmployeeByNo(String personelNumber){
  employeeDao.findOne(personelNumber);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are SQL injection attacks possible in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441193/are-sql-injection-attacks-possible-in-jpa)

Comment: Actually no.I mean JpaRepository method like findOne() findAll() etc. not custom query which we create.

Comment: Ive checked quite a few SO questions but no one seems to be answering if JpaRepositry is SQL Injection safe. We all know Non Parameterized (SELECT where)  as opposed to PreparedStatement etc are not SQL Injection safe. But wht about  Repository.find() etc?